# Cannot find "Paths and symbols" in Properties->C/C++ General in Eclipse 2023-12

Tags: eclipse-cdt, espressif-idf

I'd like to use a library from   akshayvernekar on github :

After I imported the project, directly after double-click on "main", here is my error message :

**Message :**

```
 An exception occurred invoking extension: org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent for object P/HX711_IDF-master
```

**Exception Stack Trace :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Collection.iterator()" because "c" is null
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.getBinaryParser(CModelManager.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.getLibraryReferences(CProject.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.cview.LibraryRefContainer.getChildren(LibraryRefContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.cview.CViewContentProvider.getProjectChildren(CViewContentProvider.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.cview.CViewContentProvider.getChildren(CViewContentProvider.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.navigator.CNavigatorContentProvider.getChildren(CNavigatorContentProvider.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.navigator.CNavigatorContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(CNavigatorContentProvider.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.pipelineChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$1.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.internalGetChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1448)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getRawChildren(TreeViewer.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:850)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedState(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2591)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator.handleDoubleClick(CommonNavigator.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer.handleDoubleClick(ProjectExplorer.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator$2.run(CommonNavigator.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator.lambda$2(CommonNavigator.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleDoubleSelect(CommonViewer.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4273)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4071)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
```

**Session Data :**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.30.0.20231201-1200
java.version=17.0.9
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -data file: <path_to_file>/eclipse-workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
```

Also two other errors, with those messages.

**Message :**

```
 Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.navigator".
```

**Message :**

```
An internal error occurred during: "Searching for Binaries (HX711_IDF-master)".
```

I thought I could solve this error by going on Path and Symbols to include the binary path file but it seems the window "Paths and Symbols" doesn't exist anymore. I tried to go and Preferences->Setting and Properties Page Settings-> Multiple Configurations but nothing helps me. I also didn't found any conversation about this issue. Can someone give me some clues to solve this error?

My blinky and helloworld has been compiled without any issue so I guess the problem is about the library and the missing binary files inside the project.

Thank by advance!

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with `eclipse.buildId=` and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like `<`). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I modified the issue by adding som information according your advices!